# sharepoint button flow only runs for Owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, button

I have a button flow I've added to a SharePoint list.  The button flow is triggered by a "manual trigger" action.  It is a parent flow that calls a child flow via an http request.  This button is saved to a list template which is deployed among several subsites in a project management solution.  It looks as follows:

[image: flow]

Everything works perfectly for me, the Owner, but when users attempt to run this flow it fails to initiate.  Meaning, it doesn't even run in Power Automate at all so I can't debug since there is no record of it in the Run log.

The column that has been formatted as a button includes the following JSON:

```
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
 "elmType": "button",
 "txtContent": "Submit Artifact",
 "customRowAction": {
   "action": "executeFlow",
   "actionParams": "{\"id\":\"2d2fb5d9-6905-40a3-92c4-8cc271a71bf4\", \"headerText\":\"Success, submited!\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Processing\"}"
 },
  "style": {
   "background-color": "#c8e0d9",
   "color": "#4c4c4c",
   "cursor": "pointer",
   "font-size" : "1em",
   "border-radius" : "10px",
   "min-width" : "100px",
   "text-align" : "center",
   "height" : "2px",
   "padding" : "3px",
   "margin" : "2px"

}
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of to include:

- ensuring my test users are added to the SP site the list is located with 'Contribute' permissions.  [They can add items to the list so I know this to be true].
- Providing 'Run-Only' permissions to the user accounts directly in the Flow settings.

Is there anything I am missing?  As an aside, there are no connections added to this flow.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP action is a premium action. Therefore it requires a premium license. *Everyone* who runs the parent flow will need a premium license. Unless you are using a per flow premium license.

[image]

As a workaround, you can create a **Solution**. The trick is that within a Solution, you are allowed to call child Flows for free. Just use an action called "[Run a Child Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows#create-the-parent-flow-in-a-solution)"

Comment: Hi @Denis.  I thought this as well.  But I have a PowerApps canvas app with a flow associated with it.  It also has a HTTP Request, but this one works fine.  From my understanding, flows with a PowerApps trigger runs in the user context of whomever filled out the PowerApps canvas app.  Why does it work here & not in the other instance?

Comment: I am not sure why it works in another instance. Maybe because Microsoft does not enforce it in some cases.  Also, I need to see both workflows to tell the difference.

Comment: The major significant difference is in the PowerApps flow it has my SP user credentials embedded in the parentFlow.  The button Flow has no connections associated with it.  If using a Solution to run a child flow, I'm unable to initiate the parent flow from the SP list.